# Audio byte stream from serial port

Tags: audio-streaming, usb-modem, hyperterminal, com-port

I am working on a `USB modem` project and I can see from `hyperterminal` that when a call is in progress, a certain `COM` port throws a stream of bytes.

What I want to do is to save this stream to disk and later play back.

I have tried copying all bytes into a file and naming it something like `audio.wav`. But the Windows media player or VLC media player failed to play that.

Can somebody suggest a way to parse the stream into a playable audio?

Comment: The *"stream of bytes"* is not audio data; you cannot turn that data into *"playable audio"*.  The data that you're capturing would be the data sent by the other (remote) modem.  It could be text, it could be an executable, it's whatever data or file the other side is sending.

Comment: @sawdust, thanks for reply. In some way I am sure that the stream contains audio bytes, but not sure of it's encoding format. so the question would be, is there any way to identify the properties.

Comment: Why are you so sure it's *"audio bytes"*?

Comment: @sawdust, on this gsm modem I have, it provides two COM ports, and when I call the modem from another phone, and when I issue ATA on one COM port other other one starts streaming bytes and when I speak something to it, I see the pattern changes.

Comment: You could try playing with the file in [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/about/).